# Does kafka producer reconnect fs2.Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, fs2

the microservice does not always switch to another kafka node, in case of loss of connection with the node to which it was connected and simply crashes.

If we create a producer and transfer several servers to his settings(withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers)), but in case of loss of communication with one of the Kafka nodes, will the producer try to switch to another or not?

code Scala FS2.KAFKA:
KafkaProducer.resource(ProducerSettings.withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers))

Comment: I guess fs2 used Kafka Java lib under the hood which handles such scenarios just fine. Do you have any evidence of the contrary?